# App engine flex nodejs worker_connections error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I deployed a nodejs server to app engine flex.
I am using websockets and should expect around 10k concurrent connections at the moment.

At around 2000 websockets connections I get this error:
`[alert] 33#33: 4096 worker_connections are not enough`

There is no permanent way to edit the nginx configuration in a nodejs runtime.
Isn't 2k connections on on instance quite low?

My yaml config file :

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: web

network:
  session_affinity: true

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 3
  disk_size_gb: 10

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [public issue 1](https://issuetracker.google.com/140884264) [public issue 2](https://issuetracker.google.com/38243437) increasing the number of instance night increase the worker_connections. Also [reducing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings) the memory of each instance allow the instance scale up at a lower threshold. This may help with keeping the number of open connections below 4096 which should be constant across any size instance. You can change the worker_connections value for one instance SShing into the VM.

Nginx config is located in /tmp/nginx/nginx.conf and you can manually change it as follows:

```
sudo su

vi /tmp/nginx/nginx.conf #Make your changes

docker exec nginx_proxy nginx -s reload
```

Apart from the above workaround there is another [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/140997723) for implementation of a feature to allow users to change nginx.conf settings. and feel free to post there if you have any other queries.

Comment: I can not really change the config, because "all changes made in the VM while in debug mode are temporary and all changes are lost when debug mode is disabled."
So the only solution seems to raise the number of instances :-( which I think I can do with the config parameter target_concurrent_requests.

Comment: @httpete As per this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/140997723) change nginx.conf settings is a FR at this moment

Comment: Yes indeed. It is annoying because right now with one instance I can only handle 2k websockets and it is going to be very expensive if I have to deploy a lot of instances...